# Qual é a vantagem de salvar inteiros no campo que quero salvar preços?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel, oracle

Estava lendo sobre construção de API RESTFUL com laravel, e notei uma chama interessante que me vez questionar se o modo como sempre salvei "dinheiro" no banco de dados.

Existe algum problema em salvar como Double campos do tipo valor?

O blog dizia: "Notice that price is an integer. PLEASE, I BEG YOU! NEVER STORE YOUR PRICE DATA AS DOUBLE!

ALWAYS STORE IT AS INTEGER!"

Referencia: https://medium.com/@devlob/creating-apis-in-laravel-5-5-using-api-resources-9850c1b70efb

Comment: Acho que isso responde: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219211/qual-a-forma-correta-de-usar-os-tipos-float-double-e-decimal/219465#219465

Comment: Ok, esse ponto sobre float/decimal, ok, mas ele diz para usar INTEGER... So...?

Comment: Um número de ponto fixo (`decimal`) e um inteiro são a mesma coisa.

Comment: @HananiaMizrahi, qualquer dúvida adicional, creio que comentar nas respostas da outra pergunta pode resultar em ótimas réplicas. Principalmente na resposta do Maniero, o conhecimento dele não tem fim (já a minha eu espremi tudo para escrever aquela resposta)